# Cannot connect to website running on a node server at aws ec2 instance.

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have done this for windows instance earlier but not able to do the same on ubuntu.

I am running a [Website](https://github.com/vishalydv23/SurveyWebsite) on node server on an ubuntu aws-ec2 instance. But not able to connect to it from outside. The website is running fine on the instance and can be accessed using localhost. It is running on the port: 8080.

I have added this port number in inbound rules of security groups along with other port: 80. [Screenshot of inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxHm1.jpg).

I have also added the rule in ufw(firewall) to allow http request. [Screenshot of ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnaiB.jpg).

I am trying to access the website through this link: http://ec2-52-87-224-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/ but receiving can't connect error.

Comment: Sorry - gotta ask but is the server running and on port 8080?  It has a very quick connection refused response which makes me think that it's not listening correctly.

Comment: You are binding your webserver (https://github.com/vishalydv23/SurveyWebsite/blob/master/server.js#L43). Change that and it'll work.

Comment: @weirdpanda Thanks, that worked. Regards

Comment: @Vishal, I have posted it as an answer! Please accept it so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likes you're binding the server to the local interface in the following line:

`...
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port, "localhost");
...`

Change that and it should work perfectly! When you bind the server object, Node accepts connections **only** from that interface.